# media keys don't work on Music app - OSX Catalina

Tags: keyboard, catalina, music.app, smart-keyboard

Ever since I upgraded my mac to OSX Catalina (10.15.3) the Music app (1.0.3.1) stopped responding to the media keys (ie pause/play/fast forward etc).

I searched online but couldn't find anything that works. Advice?

Comment: when the app is in foreground or background ?

Comment: It doesn't work in either case, it should work in both.